# Writing to a recursiveopenstruct object when using an array as a refernce for nesting

Tags: ruby

I’m trying to store references to a nested object in an array and then write to that object. I'm using the [recursive-open-struct](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct) gem.

```
require 'recursive-open-struct'

@nesting_refs = ['foo','bar', 'baz']
@ros = RecursiveOpenStruct.new()
@ros.send(@nesting_refs.join('.') + '=', "something")  
@ros.to_h

# returns 
#{:"foo.bar.baz"=>"something"} 

# expected 
#{
#  foo: 
#    bar:
#      baz: "something"
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `send` on an instance of RecursiveOpenStruct with a string like `foo.bar.baz`, you are *not* doing the same thing as something like `my_ros.foo.bar.baz = 'something'`.

In the former case, you're calling a method whose name is `foo.bar.baz`.  In the second case, you are calling `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in 3 separate calls.

Put otherwise, in the former case, you are asking `send` to look up the method name `foo.bar.baz` in the list of methods, and call it with the provided values. In the latter case, the Ruby interpreter is parsing your expression into the separate method calls `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` using the `.` delimeter.

Comment: thanks for answering! Are you suggesting that I use three seperate calls?

Comment: I don't know (yet) how that would be implemented.  I tried something I thought should work but it didn't. ;) I'd want a method like `create_nested_value_dynamically(recursive_os, value, names)`.

Comment: After looking at the gem's code some more (at https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct/blob/master/lib/recursive_open_struct.rb), I still can't figure out how this would be done.  I suggest contacting the author. You could of course build a source code string and call `eval` on it, but that's ugly.